# Unable to connect to mongodb as docker compose service from another service

Tags: mongodb, docker, docker-compose

when I launch my application using docker-compose, I get an error that my application cannot connect to the database, although the port is exposed and they are in the same network...
This is my docker-compose.yml file:

```yaml
version: '3'

volumes:
  db-data:
    driver: local

  mongo-config:
    driver: local

services:
  pulseq-mongodb:
    image: mongo:latest
    container_name: server-mongodb
    restart: always
    networks:
      - server-net
    ports:
      - "27017:27017"
    expose:
      - 27017
    volumes:
      - db-data:/data/db
      - mongo-config:/data/configdb

  server:
    image: my-server:0.0.1-pre-alpha.1
    container_name: server
    restart: always
    networks:
      - server-net
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
    depends_on:
      - server-mongodb

networks:
  server-net:
    driver: bridge
```

I'm getting the following error on startup:

```
server          | 2021-11-01 13:05:10.409  INFO 1 --- [localhost:27017] org.mongodb.driver.cluster               : Exception in monitor thread while connecting to server localhost:27017
server          | 
server          | com.mongodb.MongoSocketOpenException: Exception opening socket
server          |       at com.mongodb.internal.connection.SocketStream.open(SocketStream.java:70) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.2.3.jar:na]
server          |       at com.mongodb.internal.connection.InternalStreamConnection.open(InternalStreamConnection.java:143) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.2.3.jar:na]
server          |       at com.mongodb.internal.connection.DefaultServerMonitor$ServerMonitorRunnable.lookupServerDescription(DefaultServerMonitor.java:188) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.2.3.jar:na]
server          |       at com.mongodb.internal.connection.DefaultServerMonitor$ServerMonitorRunnable.run(DefaultServerMonitor.java:144) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.2.3.jar:na]
server          |       at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
```

I tried to use many solutions, but nothing helped me. Any answer will be helpful.
Thanks.

Comment: The `server` container is configured to connect to a mongo-db running on `localhost:27017`. It should, however, be configured to connect to `server-mongodb:27017`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I fixed this by using the container name, instead of `localhost` in the application configuration.